# why does GPG store different things in a bash var compared to a file

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, gnupg

I am trying to decrypt a file to a bash variable and then pipe that to zcat and then pipe that mysql.  Sending the output to file is not an option as it is a specified requirement.

so what I have is:

```
temp=$(gpg --batch --quiet --yes --passphrase=XXXXXX --decrypt file.sql.gz.gpg)
{ zcat preprocess.sql.gz; echo $temp | zcat; } | mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PWD --host=$DB_HOST $DB_ID
```

The response is a correctly unzipped preprocess file followed by:

```
zcat: stdin is encrypted -- not supported
```

However when I do:

```
gpg --batch --quiet --yes --passphrase=XXXXXX --decrypt file.sql.gz.gpg > tempfile.sql.gz
zcat preprocess.sql.gz tempfile.sql.gz | mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PWD --host=$DB_HOST $DB_ID
```

It works as expected.  However as I said we do not want any decrypted files hanging around on the server for any length of time (some of the mysl imports take hours) so writing the file and then deleting it is not a starter.

So the question is why does gpg store something different in the $temp variable as compared to the file? and what can I do about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However as I said we do not want any decrypted files hanging around on
>   the server for any length of time ...

Instead of saying:

```
temp=$(gpg --batch --quiet --yes --passphrase=XXXXXX --decrypt file.sql.gz.gpg)
{ zcat preprocess.sql.gz; echo $temp | zcat; } | mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PWD --host=$DB_HOST $DB_ID
```

say:

```
{ zcat preprocess.sql.gz; gpg --batch --quiet --yes --passphrase=XXXXXX --decrypt file.sql.gz.gpg | zcat; } | mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PWD --host=$DB_HOST $DB_ID
```

And you'd even avoid a variable holding decrypted data!

Comment: Of course I am still intrigued as to why the temp var did not work as expected - but that is lower order to having it working the first place.

Comment: @gordy Most likely the problem are `\0` bytes contained in the binary data. Shell variables were never designed for that.